# How do I have a Segmented Control that calls different views for a UINavigationController?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm an iOS/ObjC newbie, and I'm trying to find the best way to do this... What I want is to have a segmented control that has three options: 1) Map View, 2) List View, and 3) Street View. The SC will be in the bottom toolbar. In all three views, they'll need to be able to tap over to a Detail View.

I tried using a UINavigationController that has the segmented control in its bottom toolbar, but when I switch views, the bottom toolbar disappears. I've also tried loading a ViewController with just the toolbar and an empty view, then loading the navigation controller into that view, but it overlays the toolbar.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For the way you described your problem you may consider using a `UITabBarController` instead of a `UINavigationController`. It should fit better your needs.

[UITabBarController](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html&ei=AuspTtKHNcGdOuGHzd0K&usg=AFQjCNE17Vky3OsDv6jcESIVf1Hu6qB8aw&sig2=KuMkY2_X1BF65YesUKZngQ)

Comment: Unfortunately, Apple documentation says UITabBarController must be the root view controller. If benwilkins wants a tabbed interface to appear later in the user experience, then his question stands.

Answer (score 0):

Its been ages, The best choice is a UITabbarController, if for some reason this is not possible there are other solutions including creating an instance of a SC in all the views or demoting the views into subviews to be put in a horizontal scrollview but only a UITabbarCOntroller will allow him to use 3 distinct navigationControllers for each of his view